# contents of a text file to email body vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email

I want to copy all contents of a text file and paste it on the email body. I've used the code below but the body doesn't contain anything. Can somebody help me with this?

```
    Dim lines As List(Of String) = File.ReadAllLines("C:\sendD.txt").ToList
    Dim sender As String = "sender@yahoo.com"
    Dim recipient As String = "receiver@yahoo.com"
    Dim emailSubject = "Test!"
    Dim oMail As New SmtpMail("TryIt")
    Dim oSmtp As New SmtpClient()

    oMail.From = sender
    oMail.To = recipient
    oMail.Subject = emailSubject
    For Each line In lines
        oMail.TextBody = line
    Next
```

Comment: You assign the content of a line to `oMail.TextBody` instead of appending it. try `oMail.TextBody = oMail.TextBody & line` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Using inputReader As New IO.StreamReader("C:\sendD.txt")
    oMail.Body = inputReader.ReadToEnd
End Using
```

or

```
For Each line In lines
    oMail.Body = oMail.Body & VbCrLf & line
Next
```

or use StringBuilder, but this all questions the need for iList. not necessary with a StreamReader.

or, using your example (remove the For Each loop):

```
Dim lines As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\sendD.txt")
oMail.Body = lines
```

also, you should be using System.Net.Mail, not .Web.Mail

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.smtpmail%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

and: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

also, i can't find this '.TextBody' property, i think you mean .Body